# Not able to use <> in Function based Indexes in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We are trying to create a function based index which has <> (not equal to) in the where clause but get an error that say

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Is there any problem in using the <> clause ? Can it be made to work in someway.

```
 CREATE INDEX IX_TEST_TABLE ON TEST_TABLE ((NVL(COL_A, 0) <> NVL(COL_B, 0));
```

Comment: What query are you trying to index? A comparitive statement will return an internal representation of a Boolean. Oracle doesn't support Boolean's in SQL and they're relatively useless in an index as there's only 2 values.

Comment: Your index expression is a boolean value which cannot be indexed. You need to include some "real" column in your index

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments

Comment: I know am deviating from the actual question but is there a way to get the stack trace of the sql query that is given in awr, i mean a way to check the flow of the query from which package or procedure that it has been triggered?

tkprof and awr both show only the sql and the elspased time, parse and fetches.

Comment: @anudeepks - you should ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the result of that comparison in a case statement to come up with an actual value, with a supported data type, rather than a boolean - which has been noted already isn't supported y Oracle as an SQL data type. What that value is doesn't really matter as long as you're consistent; you could use Y/N, 0/1, etc.

Depending on your data spread and selectivity of how you'll query, you could use a bitmap index:

```
create bitmap index ix_test_table on test_table
  (case when nvl(col_a, 0) <> nvl(col_b, 0) then 1 else 0 end);
```

And then query on the same case, of course:

```
select * from test_table
where case when nvl(col_a, 0) <> nvl(col_b, 0) then 1 else 0 end = 1;
select * from test_table
where case when nvl(col_a, 0) <> nvl(col_b, 0) then 1 else 0 end = 0;
```

Or if it's very selective only include the small subset of rows that you're interested in by utilising the fact that null values are not included in the index:

```
create index ix_test_table on test_table
  (case when nvl(col_a, 0) <> nvl(col_b, 0) then 1 end);

select * from test_table
where case when nvl(col_a, 0) <> nvl(col_b, 0) then 1 end = 1;
```

You'd need to evaluate which is appropriate for your data.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle BOOLEAN is a PL/SQL-only type, so you can't use it in SQL, not in indexes either. the function in your index is resulting in either true or false and is therefore not allowed.